# How does not appear Year Month Day when I use datetime.strptime?

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have a str '14.45.55',I want to convert  it to time type.

```
datetime.strptime("14.45.55", "%H.%M.%S")
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 14, 45, 55)
```

I hope the result of the code is datetime.datetime(14, 45, 55)

How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's called a *datetime* because it stores both date and time.

For what you want, you need to convert it to a *time*:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("14.45.55", "%H.%M.%S").time()
datetime.time(14, 45, 55)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it out:

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_format():
    input_string = '14.45.55'
    datetime_object = datetime.strptime(input_string, '%H.%M.%S').time()
    print(type(datetime_object))
    print(datetime_object)

time_format()
```